# passing string from python to c++ using ctypes - only the first character is sent

Tags: python, c++, char, ctypes

I am trying to send a multi-character string from Python to C++ using ctypes. However only the first character of each string is passed.

This is the call in Python:

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath("nodispersion.so"))
ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('nodispersion.so')).nodispersion('teststring')
```

And how I define in C++:

```
extern "C" void nodispersion(char* test)
{

    cout << "print test " << test << "\n";
}
```

Results in only 't' being printed.

Other types such as int pass fine. In addition if I define the char* in c++ it prints fine so I assume it's something in when it gets passed from Python. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Try `ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('nodispersion.so')).nodispersion(b'teststring')`. Note the `b`.

Comment: In which way do you expect the passed string to be modified? If you don't, make it `const`. This may help Python figure out what way parameters are supposed to be passed. Further, if you want to write a Python module in C++, there are existing frameworks that make integration much easier. The `cdll` approach is IMHO rather for cases where you don't have access to the sourcecode or for prototyping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dillon Davis:

> Try ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('nodispersion.so')).nodispersion(b'teststring'). Note the b

This solved my problem in the case of passing the string `'teststring'`

However I then wanted to pass a string that had been previously defined in Python as a variable. This was solved by using `bytes` function and defining encoding as 'utf8':

```
a = 'teststring'
ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('nodispersion.so')).nodispersion(bytes(a, encoding='utf8'))
```